# Collect all errors and raise reduced exception

Tags: python

The problem is simple and looks generic. I am going to collect all errors during some operations and show all of them to user.

My question is: are there any common library implementations of this pattern?

Consider the following example. I need a collection of MyClass objects. Creation of this object may fail, so the example code may look like this:

```
class MyError(Exception):
    pass


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        if foo % 2 == 0:
            raise MyError('Unable to create object with foo={}, bar={}'.format(
                foo, bar))

        self.foo = foo
```

The first example will fail on the first exception, that is not what I need:

```
def fail_on_first():
    try:
        return [MyClass(i, None) for i in range(10)]
    except MyError as e:
        raise
```

The next code has the desired behavior:

```
def collect_all_errors():
    errors = []
    objects = []

    for i in range(10):
        try:
            objects.append(MyClass(i, None))
        except MyError as e:
            errors.append(e)

    if errors:
        raise MyError('\n'.join(e.message for e in errors))

    return objects
```

But it is not general enough. Lets try to generalize it:

```
class Args:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs


def collect_all_errors_generalized(exception_type, callable, argslist):
    errors = []
    objects = []

    for args in argslist:
        try:
            objects.append(callable(*args.args, **args.kwargs))
        except exception_type as e:
            errors.append(e)

    if errors:
        raise exception_type('\n'.join(e.message for e in errors))

    return objects
```

The appilcation code is:

```
try:
    objects = collect_all_errors_generalized(
        MyError, MyClass, [Args(i, 'bar') for i in range(10)])
except MyError as e:
    print(e)
```

Or with no args:

```
def collect_all_errors_generalized_lambdas(exception_type, callables):
    errors = []
    objects = []

    for callable in callables:
        try:
            objects.append(callable())
        except exception_type as e:
            errors.append(e)

    if errors:
        raise exception_type('\n'.join(e.message for e in errors))

    return objects

def create_factory(mytype, *args, **kwargs):
    return lambda: mytype(*args, **kwargs)

try:
    collect_all_errors_generalized_lambdas(
        MyError, [create_factory(MyClass, i, 'bar')
                  for i in range(10)])
except MyError as e:
    print(e)
```

So, the questions once again:

1. Is it common pattern?
2. Are there any good implementations of it or useful snippets?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't know why do you think this should be a good idea.

About the questions:

1: No, this is not a common pattern. Exceptions are most used to handle issues on code, sometimes to control the flow.

2: Since it is not a good idea, I don't think this is a good implementation or even an useful snippet, anyway...

Here is an "generic" decorator that you can pass as argument which `exception` you want to log.

```
def exceptloger(exceptions=None):
    def wrapper(func):
        def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if 'excepts' not in globals():
                global excepts
                excepts = []
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                excpt = e.__class__.__name__
                if exceptions and excpt in exceptions:
                    excepts.append({excpt: e.message})
                if exceptions == 'all':
                    excepts.append({excpt: e.message})
        return func_wrapper
    return wrapper
```

Decorate the methods you want to handle

```
class MyError(Exception):
    pass

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        if not foo % 2:
            raise MyError('Unable to create object with foo={}, bar={}'.format(foo, bar))

@exceptloger('MyError')
def fail_on_first():
    results = []
    for i in range(10):
        results.append(MyClass(i, None))
    return results

@exceptloger('all')
def zerodivison():
    return 1 /
```

Results

```
fail_on_first()
zerodivison()

print excepts
```

There is a great pitfall here, that decorator defines a global var. It may get out of control, so be careful using this!